# Obtener los registros que no están en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Buena;

Tengo la siguiente consulta;

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_inicio_primera_etapa
INNER JOIN data_base_ct
ON data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
WHERE data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
```

Y me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo bien, ahora quiero lo opuesto, quiero los registros que no están, intente invertir la consulta de la siguiente manera;

```
SELECT *
FROM data_base_ct
INNER JOIN data_inicio_primera_etapa
ON data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
WHERE data_base_ct.codct <> data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
```

Pero no no obtengo ningun registro;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Albert que sentido tiene : ON 
data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct 
WHERE 
data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes 2 condiciones que se contradicen:

```
ON data_base_ct.codct = data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
```

y

```
WHERE data_base_ct.codct <> data_inicio_primera_etapa.codigo_ct
```

Es imposible que las 2 condiciones sean ciertas al mismo tiempo para un registro. Si la primera condición es cierta, la segunda debe ser falsa, y vice versa. Por eso no te devuelve ningún registro.

Si deseas conseguir los registros que no están en otra tabla, en mi opinión lo más sencillo es usar la claúsula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM data_base_ct t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM data_inicio_primera_etapa t2
                    WHERE t2.codigo_ct = t1.codct)
```

**Edición**

Seguimiento a los comentarios, no me sorprendería si MySQL tienes sus caprichos en la forma de ejecutar la consulta con el `NOT EXISTS`, de modo que te dejo otras consultas equivalentes, pero que tal vez ejecutan más rápido, si deseas probarlos y compararlos.

Con `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM data_base_ct t1
  LEFT JOIN data_inicio_primera_etapa t2
    ON t2.codigo_ct = t1.codct
 WHERE t2.codigo_ct IS NULL
```

Con `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM data_base_ct
 WHERE codct NOT IN (SELECT codigo_ct
                       FROM data_inicio_primera_etapa)
```

Comment: Excelente ! muchas gracias

Comment: Una interrogante, Por que me tarda tanto en realizar la consulta, la tabla data_inicio_primera_etapa  tiene 19,000 registros y la data_base_ct  tiene 25,000 y los campos con los que estoy consultando son ambos indice

Comment: No sé. Si los 2 campos tienen índice como dices, no debería ser tan lento. Habría que examinar el execution plan. ¿Cuanto tarda?

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para agregar 2 consultas más que darían el mismo resultado, pero que tal vez con MySQL ejecutan más rápido. Puedes probarlos y comparar. Me interesa saber el resultado de la comparación si lo llegas a hacer.

Comment: Probando con LEFT JOIN "Mostrando filas 0 - 24 (total de 4624, La consulta tardó 21.0158 segundos.)"

Comment: Probando NOT IN Mostrando filas 0 - 24 (total de 4624, La consulta tardó 0.6292 segundos.)
SELECT * FROM data_inicio_primera_etapa WHERE codigo_ct NOT IN (SELECT codct FROM data_base_ct)
Por cierto quiero los registros de la tabla data_inicio_primera_etapa con estas consultas si me da lo que quiero pero demora un montón aun indicando que tarda menos de 1 segundo, es algo ilógico pero se queda cargando hasta que me arroja la consulta.

Comment: Toma en cuenta también que no es lo mismo comparar el tiempo que toma para recuperar solo las 24 primeras filas, que recuperar el resultado entero. Algunos execution plans están optimizados para obtener el mejor tiempo para recuperar la totalidad de las filas, pero tal vez no sea la mejor solo para obtener la primera fracción del resultado. Es un tema amplio, pero te lo menciono de pasadas.

Comment: De acuerdo, de todos modos muchas gracias por todo!