# Comparar 2 tablas y devolver como resultado los registros que no aparezcan en la segunda tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

estoy intentando comparar 2 tablas las cuales son `Alumnos_2018` y `Alumnos_2019` 
sus columnas son:

- Nombre
- Curp
- Ciclo_Escolar

Lo que necesito es un query que me arroje los alumnos que ya NO estan en la tabla `Alumnos_2019` pero que si estaban en `Alumnos_2018`
Por ejemplo si en la primera tabla estaba Francisco Perez, pero en la segunda ya no se encuentra, me devuelva ese nombre.

Estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM Alumnos_2018 INNER JOIN Alumnos_2019 ON Alumnos_2018.nombre <> Alumnos_2019.nombre order by Alumnos_2018.nombre;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, estoy utilizando postgresql con el gestor PGAdmin4

Comment: ¿Nos compartes por favor lo que llevas al momento?

Comment: Por supuesto SELECT * FROM Alumnos_2018 INNER JOIN Alumnos_2019 ON Alumnos_2018.nombre <> Alumnos_2019.nombre
order by Alumnos_2018.nombre;

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega tu consulta ahí

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener los registros que no están en otra tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122789/obtener-los-registros-que-no-est%c3%a1n-en-otra-tabla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta creo que debería ser por el `CURP` ya que es el numero de identificación único, puede que los nombre de alumnos se repitan.

Para solucionarlo debes tener realizar un subconsulta sobre la tabla alumnos_2019 para conocer cuales `CURP` no se encuentra osea el resultado en `NULL`

**Para sabe que alumnos_2018 no están en alumnos_2019**

Opción 1:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM alumnos_2018
WHERE (SELECT curp FROM alumnos_2019 WHERE alumnos_2019.curp = alumnos_2018.curp) IS NULL;
```

Opción 2:

```sql
SELECT * FROM alumnos_2018
WHERE alumnos_2018.curp NOT IN (SELECT curp FROM alumnos_2019)
```

**Para saber que alumnos_2019 estan tambien en alumnos_2018**
Esta para saber cuales continuaron, exceptuando los alumnos nuevos en 2019

```
SELECT * FROM alumnos_2019
WHERE alumnos_2019.curp IN (SELECT curp FROM alumnos_2018)
```

Comment: Estimado diego te agradezco mucho, la consulta salio tal como la queria muchas gracias :)