# Consulta SQL para recuperar datos relacionando dos tablas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo 2 tablas:

- una con alumnos matriculados a un curso `tbl_cursos_als`, cuyo clave principal es el campo `curso_al_id`;
- Y una segunda con los mails que se envían a los alumnos por
  diferentes motivos `tbl_al_mails`, que contiene un campo
  `curso_al_id`.

Cada vez que se envía un mail a un alumno, se guarda un registro en `tbl_al_mails`. Así, si enviamos un mail para avisar de que un alumno puede pasar a recoger su carné (porque ha completado un curso), se graba un registro en `tbl_al_mails` con su id `curso_al_id` en el campo correspondiente. Asimismo, si enviamos un mail para avisar a este mismo alumno de que puede pasar a recoger su diploma (por haber finalizado el curso), se graba un registro en `tbl_al_mails` con su id `curso_al_id` y el id de la plantilla del diploma correspondiente en el campo `tbl_al_mails.curso_diploma_id`.

Imaginemos un curso con 3 alumnos, de manera que la tabla `tbl_cursos_als` tiene este aspecto para este curso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A un alumno de este curso se le ha enviado un mail para recoger un carné; a otro alumno se le ha enviado un mail para que pase a recoger el diploma; y al tercer alumno no se le ha enviado ningún mail. Por lo tanto, `tbl_al_mails` tiene este aspecto para los alumnos de este curso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es una consulta que me permita saber a qué alumnos matriculados en ese curso a los que NO he enviado mail.
Para saber a quién NO he enviado mail para recoger diploma utilizo la consulta:

```
SELECT t1.curso_al_id FROM tbl_cursos_als t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_al_mails t2 ON t2.curso_al_id = t1.curso_al_id 
WHERE t1.curso_id = '1529' AND t2.curso_al_id IS NULL"
```

Sin embargo, no soy capaz de escribir una consulta que me permita saber a quién NO he enviado el correo para recoger carné (es decir, aquellos que cumplan: uno, campo `curso_al_id` con un valor y campo `curso_diploma_id` nulo; o dos, aquellos cuyo 'curso_al_id' no aparezca en la tabla `tbl_al_mails`).

Espero haber explicado cuál es mi problema. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Pues, para mí el inconveniente es que no es como yo hubiera diseñado la tabla. Hubiera puesto un campo mail_enviado de tipo bit en la primer tabla, una vez enviado el mail dispararía un evento que actualice el valor del campo mail_enviado e inserte en tu otra tabla. De todas formas, puedes solucionar tu problema con alguno de [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122798)

Comment: Suena a llave compuesta, entonces le faltaría a tu JOIN `AND t2.al_id = t1.al_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu explicación me pareció algo confusa, y TODA pregunta de SQL debe incluir los script necesarios para crear las tablas y para ingresar datos de prueba.

La verdad no se si entendí bien, porque la respuesta la tienes en tu misma pregunta, me basaré en lo último que señalas:

Que requieres una consulta que:

1. campo `curso_al_id` con un valor y campo `curso_diploma_id` nulo, **O**
2. aquellos cuyo `curso_al_id` no aparezca en la tabla `tbl_al_mails`

El punto (2) lo tienes resuelto tu mismo con

```
SELECT t1.curso_al_id FROM tbl_cursos_als t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_al_mails t2 ON t2.curso_al_id = t1.curso_al_id 
WHERE t1.curso_id = '1529' AND t2.curso_al_id IS NULL
```

Ahora en el punto (1) tu mismo dices **O** (que se traduce como un `or`) y también pones que `curso_diploma_id` debe ser nulo, entonces básicamente tu mismo estas diciendo que te falta un `or curso_diploma_id is null`

Es decir

```
SELECT t1.curso_al_id FROM tbl_cursos_als t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_al_mails t2 ON t2.curso_al_id = t1.curso_al_id 
WHERE t1.curso_id = '1529' and (t2.curso_al_id IS NULL or t2.curso_diploma_id is null)
```